# Monitoring Table or Do with Print

Tags: list-manipulation, printing, monitoring, procedural-programming

Imagine I want to track the progress of constructing a complex `Table` or `Do` object by temporarily printing the iteration number. For example, if I do

```
Table[PrintTemporary[i];, {i, 20}]
```

I get

[image]

which is almost what I want, but I would rather have each print vanish at each step and get replaced by the following one so that I don't produce this huge list. Any ideas?

Comment: `Monitor[Table[Pause[0.1], {i, 0, 1, 1/100}], ProgressIndicator[i]]` or `Monitor[Table[Pause[0.1], {i, 0, 100}], i]`

Answer (score 8):

```
Monitor[Table[Pause[0.1], {i, 0, 100}], i]
```

Comment: I've been using `PrintTemporary[Dynamic[i]];Table[Pause[0.1], {i, 0, 100}]` but this is nicer.

Comment: @ChrisK I think it's pretty much the same, but [`Monitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html) is more integrated and a bit more careful with localizing the variables. Maybe someone who knows more about variable scoping can give more information on this point.